# Is it possible to merge host names on two Dnsmasq instances?

Tags: networking, dhcp, dnsmasq

I have a router and a dump AP that are connected with a wire. The router has two interfaces, one is for LAN (192.168.1.1/24) and the other for WAN. The AP also has two interfaces, one is for LAN (192.168.1.2/24), the other for guest WiFi (192.168.2.1/24). (It actually also has a LAN WiFi, but it shouldn’t be relevant in this case.)

Dnsmasq runs both on the router and the AP. On the router, it provides DHCP and DNS, combined, for LAN. On the AP, only DHCP is enabled for the guest WiFi interface to provide 192.168.2.0/24 for clients.

My question is that with this setup, LAN clients won’t be able to resolve host names on the guest WiFi, since the router Dnsmasq is not cognizant of them, and it seems impossible for the router to take over guest WiFi’s DHCP, since it’s based on AP’s interfaces, so is there a way to automatically “merge" the host names on both Dnsmasq instances? If not, what would be an elegant setup to make it work?

Some of the devices connecting to LAN/WiFi are locked down that I have no control over their host names, so it's not possible to use qualified host names to ask Dnsmasq to forward domains that meant for LAN or WiFi accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLAN trunking should be used and only let one Dnsmasq instance to manage the DHCP for both the router and AP.